# Search node by ID

Tags: search, nodes, gephi

I've loaded a dataset having ID for each node in the graph, I've to search for a node by ID. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

> … if I've to search for a node with some ID. How do I do it?

`Data Laboratory` > `Filter` > `Id` > `[type id]`

then

`[Right-click node in filter result(s)]` > `Select on Overview`

Switching to `Overview` now displays the graph centered on- and zoomed into selected node.